# Online SQL reference for DB2

Tags: sql, reference, db2

Do you know of any good online SQL Reference for DB2. I need it for someone who will be moving from Oracle to DB2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The manual perhaps?
http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg27009554

Answer (score 3):

DB2 Information Center is a good place to start:
DB2 V9.5:
https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0004100.html

DB2 V9.1
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0011049.htm

Answer (score 2):

Thought I would add some more links which i discovered from my search

http://mysite.verizon.net/Graeme_Birchall/id1.html

http://delicious.com/search?p=db2%2Bsql%2Breference&u=&chk=&context=main&fr=del_icio_us&lc=0

Answer (score 2):

Is it DB2 on mainframe or other systems?. Manuals and redbooks are pretty good for db2 on mainframe. Also the listserv in idug is pretty active.

DB2 9 for Developers  by Philip K. Gunning  and Db2 certification guides by roger E sanders are excellent books for DB2 on other systems.

Answer (score 0):

[FREE Book- Getting Started with DB2 Express-C](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/db2/free+book-+getting+started+with+db2+express-c)

> - Find out what DB2 Express-C is all about
> - Understand DB2 architecture, tools, security
> - Learn how to administer DB2 databases
> - Write SQL, XQuery, stored procedures
> - Develop database applications for DB2
> - Practice using hands-on exercises